# Gap in my resume

Tags: interviewing

I have a heart condition and recently developed depression.  I left a job because the workload was too much for me, but this also helped to create my depressive state as I always wanted to be a full time contributor to society.  How do I explain this absence during a job interview?  My depression is better but my heart condition will never be.  It is mostly manageable.

Answer (score 1):

By all means mention you took time off to deal with your heart condition and that it's ongoing but under control. But best not to mention your mental problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't feel pressured to disclose that information unless you want to. Plenty of people have gaps in their resumes for various reasons--family issues, career changes, travel plans. A few months or even a year missing on your resume wouldn't raise as many eyebrows as you'd think. You went through something personal and I think it's fair to keep the details to yourself. In the case you are asked about the gap during your interview, you can say it was for health/personal reasons (that are now under control) and most likely no one would push the issue further.